# What components should I purchase at AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, vps, amazon-web-services, cloud-computing

This might sound silly question, but it is a real problem which I need help in regards.
Unlike "normal" VPS providers I used to such as linode.com and slicehost.com, at AWS they have all those fancy made up words which each require looking at their internal dictionary to explain you what it means.

They call this "[simple calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html)" but this is the most complex UI I have come across in long time.

I need a plain vanilla linux server which I already figured should be the **Large** from the **Standard Reserved Instance** and Large, it shall have a route-able IP address and internal one so I can connect few instances from the 'LAN'.

I do not need any database services or messaging queue or anything else.

Can one tell me the items I should purchase?

Comment: Nobody can determine for you what components will meet your needs. Please contact Amazon and speak with one of their sales engineers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do to get what you are looking for is to choose an instance size, as you've already done, and spin up an instance of that size. Each instance is allocated a routable public IP address, so you don't need to purchase an Elastic IP. As an earlier answerer pointed out, you will want to consider whether you want an EBS-backed instance or an ephemeral instance. If you need decent I/O performance, use an ephemeral instance and take regular backups, EBS is a dog at I/O performance (which makes it crazy that they charge for I/O on EBS instances, but at least the cost is minimal).

If you intend to run this system for a long time (10+ months, last I calculated), you are better off getting a 1 year reservation. I haven't done the math on 3 year reservations yet.

But, aside from the excess information above, all you want is a single instance.

Comment: that elastic ip confused me. thanks for clarifying.